# In Java: List, ArrayList and Map, HashMap

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

Is List:ArrayList::Map:HashMap ?

And if not, what are the differences in how these relate to each other?

Comment: Do you understand what a Map/List is? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395814/difference-between-hashmap-and-array-list-in-java/2395965#2395965

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking whether or not HashMap implements the Map interface, like ArrayList implements the List interface, then yes.

```
public class ArrayList<E>
extends AbstractList<E>
implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, Serializable

public class HashMap
extends AbstractMap
implements Map, Cloneable, Serializable
```

Answer (score 2):

List and Map are interfaces their implementations are ArrayList and HashMap

Answer (score 2):

Yes. An ArrayList is a concrete implementation of a List, and a HashMap is a concrete implementation of a Map.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just as an ArrayList is an implementation of the List interface, similarly, HashMap is an implementation of the Map interface.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an ArrayList implements the List interface and is a collection of objects which you can access using an index just like an 'array'.

HashMap implements the Map interface and maps keys to values just like a 'hashtable'.