# Which collection is better to store data from multi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, collections, multidimensional-array

I have a `multi-dimensional array of string`. I am willing to convert it into some collection type, so that I can add, remove and insert elements according my wish. In array I can not remove element at particular position.

I need such collection in which I can remove data at particular position, also able to add data at any position. 
Also dont forget I have multi-dimension array, so the collection should also able to store multidimensional data.
Which collection will be suitable for my requirments?

Comment: My data is in `String` format, ie. `("yes","abbbc")`

Comment: Is it a sparse array (i.e. most cells are empty)? Do you need to iterate over all the non-null elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) should do what you need. For instance:

```
List<List<String>> stringList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();  //A List to store a list of strings
```

or...

```
List<String[]> myNumberList = new ArrayList<List<String[]>();   //A List to store arrays of Strings.
```

Comment: am I able to access data from arraylist by using position?

Comment: @Sachin Mhetre : `List`s are ordered `Collection`s that accessible by position. [See the API for `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: @SachinMhetre: Yes you can.... I have provided you with a link tot he Javadoc... the least you can do is to check it out for yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have *Multi-Dimensional* array? Because I look for your sample data `("yes","abbbc")` it is for *One-Dimensional* array. But let me give you an example:

```
    // This example for multi-dimensional array of string
    String[][] arrays = new String[][]{{"aa", "bb", "cc"}, {"dd", "ee", "ff"}};
    Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> list;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        list = Arrays.asList(arrays[i]);

        map.put(i, list);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < map.get(i).size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(map.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }

    // This example for one-dimensional array of string
    String[] arr = new String[] {"aa", "bb"};
    List<String> listArr = Arrays.asList(arr);

    for(String str : listArr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

For *Multi-Dimensional* array I'm using `HashMap` and for *One-Dimensional* array I'm using `ArrayList`. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395814/difference-between-hashmap-and-array-list-in-java) if you still don't understand between those two. And please *Correct Me If I'm Wrong*

Answer (score 0):

As with any problem, you have multiple options for data-structures and you have to make a design decision based on their trade-offs (time, space).

Two data structures that immediately come to mind are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.  With a `LinkedList` you can `insert` and `remove` an element from any position in `O(1) constant time`.  With an `ArrayList` this would be linear time O(n).

However, accessing an element in an `ArrayList` is constant time (you can index into it).  Whereas, normally with a `LinkedList` you would need to traverse through it.  This problem in `LinkedList` though can be avoided though by `hashing` each of the elements, so you can find a particular node in a `linked list` in `amortized constant time`.  Of course, having a `hash` and a `linked list` is a speedier solution than an `array` though there is more overhead in terms of space.

For more information on these data-structures: [Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure), [Linked Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), [Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)  
`Java` implementations of these data structures: [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), [Hash table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Comment: I was looking for linked list, but does linked list support to store multi-dimension array data?

Comment: `Linked list` is a data-structure and can hold any type of data.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by 'multi-dimensional'?  How many dimensions?  What sort of data operations do you hope to perform?

Comment: I not talking about type, I am saying that can a linked list **node** save multiple data, ie. <string, string, integer>

Comment: Of course!!
Each `node` in a (singly)`linked list` often has two members - the `data` and the `pointer` to the next `node`.
The `data` can be any `class` or `object`.
Of course, if you wish, you can also choose to have additional data members in each node (like you mentioned - two `string` data members, one `integer` and the `pointer`), but, I would highly recommend you make use of the `object-oriented` nature of `java` :)

Comment: Suppose my array is of size arr[10][3]; So can node save 3 values at a time?

Comment: Yes.  Please read the wikipedia article on linked lists (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) to understand them better.