# What's this collision-detection-method called?

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics

So, you have an multicolor picture that you print on the screen, and you have black and white picture that you use to check pixel-perfect collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this in a system I dubbed **Collision Masking,** but some people call it **Point-Square** or **Point-Point** collision.

The basic idea is you have one image that is the *displayed graphics,* and another image, usually black and white, that is the *collision mask*. Then, you have a parser that checks the world for a position's color, if it's black, there is collision(*assuming you were in a previously white pixel*), if white, you are free to go there.

Note that this method can be very slow. Would definitely recommend **hashing** your collection of collision pixels for quick processing. It was also highly recommended to store the applicable pixels, *since you want 100% precision*, into **rectangular sections** to speed up the checking process further. Additionally, I'd recommend implementing a **zoning** feature, checking only the pixels around or at the area you are interested in, into the collision check.

The main issue with this type of perfect masking is that it's reasonably slow but if you follow my suggestions above you should be fine.

You can also extend this thought process to 3D collision as well but you need to incorporate colors into your masks.

Comment: I'm noob, so would someone please explain me, what does mean "hashing your collection of collision pixels"?

Comment: No problem do you understand the basics of hashing?

Comment: I'm assuming you are reading your collection of masks into some kind of storage, and that each element in this contains the pixel color and location.

You should then make a hash table with the pixel's position as the key and the pixel's color as the value. This way it is an O(1) retrieval of the possibility of collision. This puts the emphasis on the loading overhead as this table has to be populated at the "world's" start.

I'd also recommend doing the same thing for objects that need dynamic collision but in a separate table, and you should also check for static collision first.

Comment: So, i turn each pixel of image into an entry on a list?

Comment: Yes but a non-hashed list will take forever to parse through. Especially once multiple objects start searching for collision.

Comment: What's the difference between hashed- and non-hashed list?

Comment: Simply: a hashed list, also known as a hash tree, hash map, or dictionary, allows you to access a specific element by knowing its key, which you define and in this case it is useful to is the pixels location as a key. A non-hashed list, also known as an array, allows you to access a specific element but it's position in the list. This is not useful for collision needs as it is hard to keep track of what index a pixel is located in and requires parsing. This parsing makes find a pixel O(n) to O(nlog(n)), much slower than the hashing method which is O(1) to O(n).

Comment: Further reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395814/difference-between-hashmap-and-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i understand what is meant by hashes!

Comment: No problem! I would also recommend analyzing why you need 100% perfect collision as most system can seem "perfect" and still just use shape primitives for collision rather than absolute pixels or vectors. Plus it's way faster to use prims.

Comment: Why colors in 3D? Are you referring to surface normals or percentage cell occupation ?

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah to maintain the same masked collision system in 3D, although using vector prims usually makes more sense, you'd basically assign, or really make a deciphering algorithm,  a color value to a corresponding range of z values for the "depth" of the collision. That way you can tell how high or low and object is and if your current plane's color intersects with and objects depth.

Comment: Not a fan of this system for 3D as you can do the same thing by just keeping track the vectors and collision prims.