# What is the main difference between Array and Hashmap in java?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap

In Java, Array and HashMap are used as collections.But I couldn't understand in which situations we should use Array and which time to use HashMap. 
What is the major difference between both of them?
I'm confused about the difference between the Array and HashMap.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: @ScaryWombat This question seems to be about `HashMap` vs array, not `ArrayList`, so that is not truly a duplicate.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry I got confused

Comment: OP - do you mean an array like `String [] myArr` ?

Comment: Simple example to answer your question would be, if you just want to store some names of your friends, use an `array`. If you want to store phone number of each of your friend against their names, use a `HashMap`. Basically `key,value` pairs are stored in `HashMap`.

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar This just describes one usage of a HashMap, it does not describe the differences he is asking for...

Comment: @RobertK That example is place to start with. OP should have googled or done a brief survey before posting this question. P.S - Not my down vote though.

Comment: Difference between ArrayList (or List) vs HashMap mostly apply to this question.  Array is simply even more restrictive than `List` given that Array has a fixed size.

Comment: Although the duplicated question (_List vs Map_) is not exactly the same as this (_Array vs HashMap_), the differences between List and Map mostly apply to this question.  Array in the sense of using as collection, is mostly the same as a List except it has fixed size.  Of course there are other differences but that shouldn't be significant in context of this question

Comment: Another candidate reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395814/difference-between-hashmap-and-arraylist-in-java. `ArrayList` is a `List` works similar to array when accessing elements.

Answer (score 2):

- [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has values, [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) has keys and values. Whereas you would access a value in array with something like this `array[1]`, you can't do that with a `HashMap`. You have to call `hashmap.get(key)` to retrieve a desired value (which means you need a key to directly access the associated value).
- HashMaps cannot have repeating keys. Therefore, if you have a `HashMap` of keys and values, you can be sure that its keys are unique (values may contain duplicates across the key-value pairs).
- Arrays will maintain your order, and you can sort them. `HashMap` makes no guarantees on what order will be used. It also makes no guarantees that the order will remain constant over time. So if you're looking for it, you might be better off with [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).
- While it is necessary to know a key to retrieve a value from `HashMap`, you also have a `contains(key)` method, which is O(1) with a properly implemented hash. It allows you to check whether a key exists in a map. It is quite useful if you store associated data and want to check whether you already have a desired key.

What both of them do have in common is that both get and put operations are (in ideal case) O(1).

Another tidbit of info: if I'm not mistaken, `HashMap`s utilize arrays (and [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)s) underneath. It's a *very* useful data structure, and quite ingenious, too.

You'd want to use HashMaps in situations where you want to associate two pieces of data with one another. Say, you have a `Restaurant` and an `Address`. You could use `Restaurant` as a key and `Address` as a value (not the best example there is, but you get the point). As for arrays, if you have a list of your favorite restaurants, array might be a good choice to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are perfectly aware of the fact that a HashMap handles key-value pairs while an array does not..

A HashMap uses a keys **HashCode** to decide at what index to store the value in an **array**. When you give a HashMap a key in order to get the associated value, it will first calculate key.hashcode() % m, where m is the length of the underlying array, and then inspect what's stored at that location.

One implementation of a HashMap might store linked lists at each array spot. If this is the case, the HashMap would now traverse the list and return a value v if the associated key and the key you provided are equal (determined by the **equals()** method).

The need to store Linkedlists at each arrayspot arises from the use of %. A hashcode could be very large, larger than the size of the array. This means that several different keys could end up generating the same indexes.

A big difference is the time complexities. In worst case a lookup in a HashMap will take O(n) time. This happens if the HashCode is implemented poorly and all the items end up with the same HashCode. In an array however, a lookup is always constant time O(1).

I hope this makes it somewhat clearer to you.

Comment: Generally theoretical answers lack clarity. Answer would have more weight-age if backed by some code snippets.

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar What do you expect, that i post a complete implementation of a HashMap?

Comment: Certainly not. The answer would have been great if you could add some code snippets that would demonstrate the behavior of `Arrays` and `HashMap`. This is just a suggestion that usually applies to most of the answers that one posts in this forum.