# Arraylist - how to?

Tags: android, arraylist

So I have this array List:

```
private ArrayList<String> output;
```

Which look like this normally once items are added looks like this:

```
["ready", "30 min", "5.2 mi", "stop"]
```

But sometimes the order can change on how the information comes in for example:

```
["30 min", "stop", "5.2 mi", "ready"]
```

What would be the best solution to get the number that is in front of `mi` and `min` since the ArrayList can change I can't use `list.get(1)` for example cause the index might be something different.

I have tried to use `list.getIndexOf("mi");` but that didn't work, kept coming back as -1 which I would think cause it wasn't an exact match.

Comment: all are strings right like `["ready", "30 min", "5.2 mi","stop"]`

Comment: @SantanuSur yes they are all Strings, the order and numbers can change though.

Comment: i have updated the answer.. please update if it works..

Comment: Depending on your needs, you may want to look at using a `HashMap` instead of an `ArrayList`. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395814/difference-between-hashmap-and-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this .. to get no before "mi"

```
for(int i =0; i<list.size();i++)
    { 
       if(list.get(i).contains("mi"))
        {
           String[] splitT = 
               list.get(i).split(" ");
            System.out
      .println("before mi is"     + splitT[0]);}
     }
```

**Note** `splitT[0]` is the answer what you want.. like this you can find for "min" too..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get an element whith a certain pattern to further work with that information. In that case you could loop through the ArrayList and check for element whether or not it matches a certain regexp. Something like this:

```
for (String s : arraylist) {

    if (s.matches("[0-9]+ mi(n)?")) //would match any number, followed by a whitespace and mi/min {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something likes this.

```
for (String item:list){
        if (item.contains("mi")&&!item.contains("min")){
            Log.d("item",item.substring(0,3));
        }
    }
```

You can do similarly for "min".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<output.size() ; i++){
   if (output.get(i).endsWith("mi")) // index i contains "mi"
   else if (output.get(i).endsWith("min")) //index i contains min not mi
}
```